# how to reduce run tiime for a simple if-else-while program

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, break

i had just started learning python,so i was practising some code at codechef
one of the problem i was trying was https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFEZQ

"Chef published a blog post, and is now receiving many queries about it. On day i, he receives Qi queries. But Chef can answer at most k queries in a single day.

Chef always answers the maximum number of questions that he can on any given day (note however that this cannot be more than k). The remaining questions (if any) will be carried over to the next day.

Fortunately, after n days, the queries have stopped. Chef would like to know the first day during which he has some free time, i.e. the first day when he answered less than k questions.

Input:
First line will contain T, the number of testcases. Then the testcases follow.
The first line of each testcase contains two space separated integers n and k.
The second line of each testcase contains n space separated integers, namely Q1,Q2,...Qn.
Output:
For each testcase, output in a single line the first day during which chef answers less than k questions.

Constraints
1≤T≤105
1≤ sum of n over all testcases ≤105
1≤k≤108
0≤Qi≤108"

so i wrote my code like this:

```
i=0

while (i<T):
    nk=input()
    q=[int(a) for a in input().split(" ")]
    n_k=nk.split(" ")
    n=int(n_k[0])
    k=int(n_k[1])
    j=0
    l=0
    while j<n:
        l=l+q[j]-k
        if l<0:
            print(j+1)
            break
        j+=1
    while j>=n:
        l=l-k
        if l<0:
            print(j+1)
            break
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

the total time limit is 1sec but my code takes 5 sec
i dont find any method to reduce time,can someone pls help me out
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `while  j >= n` is unnecessary if you have already called `print`, and if you haven't, `print(j + l//k + 1)` or something similar (please use longer and more meaningful variable names!) will directly calculate the answer.

Comment: tysm ,i understood what u wanted to say,it should have been (l//k)+n+1

Answer (score 0):

The while loop `j>=n` is badly designed: The loop condition never gets False as j is always increased and n never decreased. In general, such a loop may never terminate. In this case, it probably will terminate as l is decreased (hoping that k is always positive) and this eventually leads to a break. But a loop should always be constructed such that the condition eventually becomes False.

At the end of the loop with condition `j<n`, the new condition `j>=n` holds anyway and always will (as long as j and n are not manipulated). Thus the new condition may be `while l>=0`. (I did not check whether this, in particular, solves the actual task, however, but it will at least simplify the given code, apart from improving the style. It does at least with one check less per iteration.)

Comment: ty i got ur pt but that didnt decrease much time